# How to use Saxon XPath processor w/o coding in Java

Tags: xml, xpath, command-line, saxon

I guess I could make some XSL stylesheet, then use it as a template with parameter option to evaluate XPath expression with Saxon XSLT processor on command line, like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:evaluate($xpath-param)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Also other possibility is to use their Java API: http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/xpath-api/intro.xml but I don't know Java

Is there any way to make Saxon evaluate XPath expression from command line?
Shell script would be sufficient, too, if possible

Update:
Browsing Saxon [documentation](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/samples/shakespeare.xml), I found out about `XPathExample` sample. Unfortunately I can't make use of it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can run Saxon (XQuery) from the command line. You can do this by pointing to a file that has the XPath/XQuery using `-q` or you can pass the query string directly using `-qs`.

Here's an example of using `-qs` to process a simple XPath:

**input.xml**

```
<a>
  <b id="x"/>
  <b id="z"/>
  <b id="x"/>
</a>
```

**Saxon command line** (I used Saxon9-HE to test with)

```
java -cp "saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Query -s:"input.xml" -qs:"/a/b[@id='x']" -o:"results.xml"
```

**results.xml**

```
<b id="x"/><b id="x"/>
```

*Note: I could've made my output well-formed by changing the `-qs` to something like this: `-qs:"<results>{/a/b[@id='x']}</results>"`.*

For more command line options, look here: http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xquery/commandline.html

Comment: OK, thanks. I just started to learn XML and needed easy XPath 2.0 processor. I didn't know I could use XQuery like that. `saxon-xquery` in `/usr/bin/` which is shortcut of `java -classpath /usr/share/java/saxonb.jar net.sf.saxon.Query "$@"` can't execute above snippet parameters, but evoking literally (`saxon9he.jar`) like in your sample works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As @DanielHaley says, using XQuery from the command line is a better bet. Providing XPath from the command line wouldn't be very useful because XPath offers no way to control the formatting of the output. XPath is a subset of XQuery, so you can use the XQuery interface to evaluate XPath expressions if you choose.

Note that the current version of open-source Saxon is Saxon-HE 9.4.0.2. You can find out which version you are using with the -t option on the command line. It sounds as if you might have found an old version (Saxon-B) bundled with your Linux distribution, and @prunge has pointed you to an even older version (Saxon 6.5) which only supports XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0.

**UPDATE**: As of January 2019, the current version of Saxon is 9.9.0.2

Comment: Thanks for your input. Version is 9.0.0.4 - which is default on Ubuntu 11.04. I downloaded latest version from SourceForge after-which I executed XPath pattern successfully. I'll just uninstall Ubuntu version and make new handy shortcuts in /usr/bin/. I can't seem to find option to suppress XML Declaration from output, thou

Comment: Found out that output method can be used as parameter like this example: `\!"method=text"` in `bash`. In `sh` there is no need for backslash

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use XPath within a tool, such as [oXygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/).  Its [XPath Builder View](http://www.oxygenxml.com/xpath.html) is a very handy interface for building and testing XPath expressions.  There is a [Linux version](http://www.oxygenxml.com/download_oxygenxml_editor.html?os=Linux) of the tool, and it has built-in support for [Saxon](http://www.oxygenxml.com/validation.html#external_validation) and other processors (Xerces, LIBXML, XSV, MSXML4.0, MSXML .NET and SQC.).

[image]

Comment: Sure, but that's commercial java software, which also needs high end machine to be useful at all. For XPATH evaluation, locally or over HTTP, `saxon` or `xmllint` are more then enough, and can be integrated in any tool/editor user is comfortable with.

Comment: It is commercial s/w; so is Saxon.  :-)  Like Saxon, oXygen is very good commercial software, well worth every penny, esp if you do a variety of work with XML.  No, you don't need a high end machine; my 2 year old laptop runs it just fine.  It's a viable option given the OPs requirements; more choices is more better.

Comment: I don't think so. There are also various commercial and non commercial products that can do XPATH, or use already available processors to do the job. Oxygen is far from good suggestion: 1. It's designed to do more than just XPATH, and may confuse user that wants to do just that; 2. It requires at least good multicore CPU with lot of RAM to be usable; 3. you can buy yourself new PC for the money you pay to use XPATH processor from Java GUI, which you can do for free from terminal

Comment: I agree with James, Oxygen is a good option. It's not the best option for everyone, but it is a very good one for some people. Oxygen is quite cheap if you get the academic version and/or qualify for their outreach program (formerly "Support Life"). If it's not the best option for you, that's fine, but that doesn't diminish the value of James' answer.