# Simplest way to do basic xml parsing from unix command line

Tags: xml, perl, unix, awk, grep

I'm searching for xml files that have certain properties. For example, files that contain the following pattern:

```
<param-value>
  <name>Hosts</name>
  <description>some description</description>
  <value></value>
</param-value>
```

For such files, I'd like to parse the value of another tag, such as:

```
<param-value>
  <name>Roles</name>
  <description>some description</description>
  <value>asdf</value>
</param-value>
```

And print out the file name along with "asdf". What's the simplest way to accomplish this from the command line?

One approach I was thinking of was just using grep with the -l option to filter the matching files out, and then using xargs grep to extract the value of Roles. However, grep doesn't work well with multi-line regexes. I saw another question that showed it could be done with the -Pzo options, but didn't have any luck getting it to work in my case. Is there a simpler approach?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use a scripting language such as perl?

Comment: The simplest for me is to use [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) from the command line. Here's an example of using [XPath on the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997709/how-to-use-saxon-xpath-processor-w-o-coding-in-java/8999664#8999664). This, combined with a shell script, would do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: According to [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91791/grep-and-sed-equivalent-for-xml-command-line-processing), [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) seems to be very good for this kind of thing.

Comment: No, a perl solution would be great, preferably a compact one-liner, but I don't know the best way to go about writing it.

Comment: I had hoped to work through your problem more carefully, but I have run out of time, sorry. Anyway - [perl](http://perl-xml.sourceforge.net/faq/) has some very good modules for reading xml. In particular, the following article, [perl and xml on the command line](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/04/17/perl-xml.html), is probably of interest.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a solution that runs with just the most basic tools though, the xmlstarlet, xpath, and perl's xpath module are not installed on the system on which I'm going to perform the search.

Comment: This looks like the most portable solution which is what I need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse XML in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893585/how-to-parse-xml-in-bash)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 13):

The following linux command uses XPath to access specified values within the XML file

```
for xml in `find . -name "*.xml"`
do  
echo $xml `xmllint --xpath "/param-value/value/text()" $xml`| awk 'NF>1'
done
```

Example output for matching XML files:

```
./test1.xml asdf
./test4.xml 1234
```

Comment: Didn't knew xmllint could be used to parse xml. To me this is the best answer because it's always installed as it's a system dependency (at least on CentOS/Redhat/...)

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a couple of solutions using basic perl/awk functionality (basically a poor man's parsing of the tags). If you see any improvements using only basic perl/awk functionality, let me know. I avoided dealing with multiline regular expressions by setting a flag with I see a particular tag. Kind of clumsy but it works.

perl:

```
perl -ne '$h = 1 if m/Host/; $r = 1 if m/Role/; if ($h && m/<value>/) { $h = 0; print "hosts: ", $_ =~ /<value>(.*)</, "\n"}; if ($r && m/<value>/) { $r = 0; print "\nrole: ", $_ =~ /<value>(.*)</, "\n" }'
```

awk:

```
awk '/Host/ {h = 1} /Role/ {r = 1} h && /<value>/ {h = 0; match($0, "<value>(.*)<", a); print "hosts: " a[1]} r && /<value>/ {r = 0; match($0, "<value>(.*)<", a); print "\nrole: " a[1]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ xmlstarlet ed -u /param-value/name -v Roles -u /param-value/value -v asdf data.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<param-value>
  <name>Roles</name>
  <description>some description</description>
  <value>asdf</value>
</param-value>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Perl's [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2). You can process XML files interactively in it, or script it. The script would be something like (untested):

```
for my $file in { glob "*.xml" } {
    open $file ;
    my $param_value = //param-value[name="Hosts"] ;
    if $param_value echo $file $value/value ;
}
```