# Pseudo XML parsing with shell script

Tags: xml, scripting, sh, xmllint

For the past several days I've been trying to figure out how I can write a script to parse out what I assume is some pseudo XML file. The most I've come across is xmllint, but everything references xpath, which doesn't work for me. And I can't modify the box I'm running this on, I have to work with what I have already.

I say it's a "pseudo" XML because this is how it starts

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
            <policy name='Default' schema-version='1.2.3' valid='true' version='68.0.0' xmlns='http://www.iss.net/cml/NetworkObjects'>
                <AddressGroupList Comment='Some Comment' Name='MyNetworks'>
                    <AddressGroup>
                        <AddressName value='Network1'/>
                    </AddressGroup>
                    <AddressGroup>
                        <AddressName value='Network2'/>
                    </AddressGroup>
                    <AddressGroup>
                        <AddressName value='Network3'/>
                    </AddressGroup>
                    <AddressGroup>
                        <AddressName value='Network4'/>
                    </AddressGroup>
                </AddressGroupList>
```

Later on, in that same file, each "AddressName" item is defined, below is just one example

```
                <AddressList Comment='US Access' GUID='8BFC30C4-31B6-4038-A507-A0D1712992AD' Name='Network1'>
                    <AddressMask IPAddressMask='1.2.3.0/24'/>
                </AddressList>
```

I consider myself a pretty decent script writer, but I've always worked with flat text. I can't figure out how to parse things out of this XML type setup and I'm desperate for help.

I need to first parse out Name/comment/IPAddressMask to create host objects, and then go back and create the group objects to reference the hosts objects.

In an ideal world, my output would be something like

## Name:Type:Comment:IP:Netmask

Network1:network:US Access:1.2.3.0:24

Then

## Name:type:Comment;members

MyNetworks:Group:Some Comment;Network1, Network2, Network3, Network4

If anyone can help get me started in the right direction, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplest way to do basic xml parsing from unix command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200462/simplest-way-to-do-basic-xml-parsing-from-unix-command-line)

Comment: I think this is asking for something else than the "simplest way to do basic xml parsing".  But the question basically amounts to "teach me a scripting language, or do the task for me" so I am voting to close as Too broad.