# Search string in file via bash but only work match

Tags: linux, string, bash, file, search

Find the only string name based on the sub string name in a file.

Command used:

```
cat test.xml | grep -i current | awk -F / '{print $NF}' | tr -d
```

What works:

File content:

```
<Context path="/SomeApi" reloadable="false" docBase="http://some-domain/CURRENT/SomeApi-CURRENT.war"
```

Output (desired output):

```
SomeApi-CURRENT.war
```

What does not work:

File content:

```
<Context path="/SomeApi" reloadable="false" docBase="http://some-domain/CURRENT/SomeApi-CURRENT.war" workDir="/U01/someApi/work
```

Output:

```
work className=URLStandardContext unpackWAR=true>
```

Need output `SomeApi-CURRENT.war`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse XML in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/893585/608639), [How to parse XML using shellscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4680143/608639) and [Simplest way to do basic xml parsing from unix command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9200462/608639). I believe you need to use the proper tools to parse the XML first. Then, you can move on to extra parsing of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears, you are interested in the docBase attribute of your xml elements. Specifically those where the value string contains "current" as a substring.

```
grep -i current test.xml | grep -o " docBase=\"[^\"]*" | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev
```

But this is a somewhat crude solution. Multiple assumptions have to be made in order to guarantee correctness.

As using grep etc. is not ideal, you would probably want to check [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)  which is a command line tool for parsing xml inputs. With XPath the command could look something like this:

```
xmllint --xpath "//Context[contains(translate(@docBase,'CENRTU', 'cenrtu'), 'current')]/@docBase" test.xml | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | cut -c2- | rev
```