# could not find main class in Saxon Xquery

Tags: xquery, saxon

`java -cp  saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query` only yields the following message:

> could not find main class net.sf.saxon.Query

I have read in other threads that this is the proper command for XQuery mode in Saxon so what else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the java command in the same directory that your `saxon9he.jar` is in? (Which it would have to be with that classpath.) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997709/how-to-use-saxon-xpath-processor-w-o-coding-in-java/8999664#8999664 for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little surprised by this message, because normally when you get the classpath wrong, you get a quite different message: something like

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/saxon/Query

It could be that you're using some command line tool which tries to make the message more friendly.

Anyway, from the information given, the most probable explanation is that saxon9he.jar does not exist in the current directory.

Comment: any hints of how to use Saxon XQuery on Mac? I installed with 'brew install saxon'. But the installed `saxon` binary tool doesn't seem to have `-qs` option: `Command line option -q is not recognized. Options available: -? -a -catalog -config -cr -diag -dtd -ea -expand -explain -export -ext -im -init -it -l -license -m -nogo -now -o -opt -or -outval -p -pack -quit -r -repeat -s -sa -scmin -strip -t -T -threads -TJ -TP -traceout -tree -u -val -versionmsg -warnings -x -xi -xmlversion -xsd -xsdversion -xsiloc -xsl -xsltversion -y`

Comment: Commenting on someone else's question from 4 years ago is the wrong way to do things on SO. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify full path to your saxon9he.jar, for example, for me worked the following command when initially I had the same error, as you described:

```
java -cp "C:\SaxonHE9-7-0-5J\saxon9he.jar" net.sf.saxon.Query your-xquery-file.xq
```